# python System error 53 or 67 has occurred

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

with this code

```
command = 'net use v: \\sshfs\user@1.2.3.4!1234\\\\ /USER:user *'
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
p.wait()
```

I get

```
System error 67 has occurred.
The network name cannot be found.
```

With this `command = 'net use v: \\\\sshfs\user@1.2.3.4!1234\\\\\\\\ /USER:user *'`

I get

```
System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

None of them work.

But when I run command `net use v: \\sshfs\user@1.2.3.4!1234\\\\ /USER:user *` in standard command line, it works ok. Any idea please?

Comment: You didn't escape the backslash before user. (i.e. you didn't double it). You could also just use a raw string, where you wouldn't have to double it (note the r at the beginning): `r'net use v: \\sshfs\user@...'`

Comment: Why 4 trailing backslashes? The system will collapse that down to 1 backslash. Also, it's not a shell command, so use the default `shell=False` option instead of `shell=True`.

Comment: I tried `r` and also `shell=False`,but  no progress.

Comment: It should work with a raw string: `subprocess.call(r'net use v: "\\sshfs\user@1.2.3.4!1234" /USER:user *')`

Comment: I tried your raw string - in python it does not work (and ends with "System error 53 has occured. The network path was not found"). But when I execute the same command in Windows command line, it works correctly. Strange.